# Unable To Get Static Files To Load In Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to load js files in my spring boot application, but when I try to load "/resources/static/js/jsfile.js" using the url `http://localhost:8080/js/jsfile.js` I am getting a 404 not found error.

I need to prevent this controller from getting called when I try to load something in src/main/resources/static/

```
@GetMapping("/{username}/{slug}")
public String single(@PathVariable("username") String username, @PathVariable("slug") String slug, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", postService.getSinglePost(slug, username));
    return "/post/single";
}
```

After reading other solutions I tried creating this but I'm still getting 404 errors.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mapping in Spring MVC must be un-ambiguous. 

Try to avoid using generic URLs like /{username}/{slug}, this would map your whole application. 
Try /users/{slug} instead


Is not necesary to map js/ and css/ since they are automatic mapped by Boot

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same url structure as fiverr.com. They have fiverr.com/{username} to view a profile, and fiverr.com/{username}/{slug} to view a gig. Would it be possible to achieve that in spring?

Comment: See the https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot